# Proposition 1 Ch.2 in Royden's Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

According to the Proposition 1 Ch.2 in the book Real Analysis by Royden:

> It remains to show that $m^*([a, b])\ge b- a.$ But this is equivalent to showing that if ${\{I_k}\}^{\infty}_{k=1}$ is any countable collection of open, bounded intervals covering $[a, b]$, then $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {l(I_k)} \ge b- a .$$

But that's not true, I believe. Because $$m^*([a, b])\le m^* (\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} {I_k}) \le  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {m^*(I_k)} $$ does not apply $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {m^*(I_k)} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {l(I_k)} \ge b- a .$$

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing to keep in mind is that $m^*([a,b])$ is the *infimum* of all such sums. Thus if $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty l(I_k) \ge c$ for every collection $\{I_k\}$ of open intervals whose union contains a set $E$, then upon taking infimum you get $m^*(E) \ge c$ too.

Comment: Am I getting this right? : for every collection ${\{I_k}\}$, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {l(I_k)} \ge b- a$ so is $m^*([a,b]) = \inf (\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {l(I_k)}) \ge b- a$; ?

Comment: Exactly. $b-a$ is a lower bound of the sums, so it does not exceed the least upper bound.